# Why data is not getting persisted on disk when memory is full in redis?

Tags: memory, redis, configuration-files, disk

In redis.conf file we have set max memory policy to  eviction policy to allkeys-random and allocated 4GB as max memory. We inserted 5 million keys but when we actually checked the dbsize it only showed about 2.5 million only.

So I have a question, does eviction policy removes keys from only memory or disk?

Ideally whenever given maxmemory is full, the keys selected for eviction should be flushed to disk so that they can be retrieved later from disk whenever required.

Conf file comments only mentions that keys will be removed, but it doesn't tell if they are removed from only memory or also from disk i.e. persistant store.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evicted keys are removed from memory. Disk snapshot is not touched. However, values on disk will also be gone when next snapshot is made.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but then we have few doubts:
So, is there no way to store large keys dataset in redis server having less memory? i.e. disk store is just used to store memory snapshot and not as a disk store in case of memory overflow?
So does this mean, redis is only suitable for applications whose total keys can fit in the available memory of redis server? Why doesn't it just swap out the keys from memory to disk and then load them back from disk whenever needed?
I tried to search redis documentation but not able to figure out these queries, so please help.

Comment: @Sohan: Yes, exactly. VM support was dropped and disk store never made it into production (or the other way around), because this is not how people normally use redis. Those features were complicating the code and slowing redis down, and they brought very little value. If you need to support datasets larger than RAM, look at other products.